# Fixx Converting to "int" failed for parameter "amount" Error

Tags: python, discord

I copied a code for deleting chat messages, but if I try to clear all, an Error occurs:

`discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Converting to "int" failed for parameter "amount"`

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount: int=None):
    if amount == "all":
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=10000000000000000000000000000000000)
        await ctx.send("Cleared the entire chat!")
        print("Cleared the chat!")
    else:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
        await ctx.send("Done!")
        print(f"Cleared {amount} messages!")
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: no... dosnt work

Answer (score 0):

It's in string form. That's why it runs fine when you compare it against "all" and errors out when you use it like an int.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount: int=None):
    if str(amount) == "all":
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=10000000000000000000000000000000000)
        await ctx.send("Cleared the entire chat!")
        print("Cleared the chat!")
    else:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
        await ctx.send("Done!")
        print(f"Cleared {amount} messages!")
```

Comment: if i put a number behind the comand everything is fine... my problem is the part before else... (if amount == "all":)

Comment: Ahh so it's the other way around I changed the code so that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is expecting an integer for the `amount` parameter, so *`all`* is a bad argument, since it's a string type.

Either you remove the int casting from the parameters definition or you use some int-castable string instead of "all".

Answer (score 0):

its simple just add a try except

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount):
    if amount == "all":
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=10000000000000000000000000000000000)
        await ctx.send("Cleared the entire chat!")
        print("Cleared the chat!")
    else :
        try:
            amount = int(amount)
        except ValueError:
            await ctx.send("Bad Argument")
            return
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
        await ctx.send("Done!")
        print(f"Cleared {amount} messages!")
```